# Directx 11 depth test not working

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, depth-buffer, directx-11

I cannot get my program to correctly choose which models to place in front.  I have followed the MSDN code exactly.  My code appears to correctly draw all polygons in a particular call of DrawIndexed, but each subsequent call seems to cause models to be drawn in the order they are drawn, not based on whether they are closer to the screen.

Here is my code for initializing Direct3d:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
sd.BufferCount = 1;
sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
sd.OutputWindow = hWnd;
sd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sd.Windowed = !fullScreen;
sd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  FeatureLevelsRequested = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
UINT               numFeatureLevelsRequested = 1;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  FeatureLevelsSupported;
HRESULT hr;
if( FAILED (hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( adapters[0], 
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, 
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    NULL, 
    NULL, 
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
    &sd, 
    &swapchain, 
    &dev, 
    &FeatureLevelsSupported,
    &devcon )))
{
    //return;
}
ID3D11Texture2D *pBack = NULL;
swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBack);

// use the back buffer address to create the render target
dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBack, NULL, &backbuffer);
pBack->Release();

// set the render target as the back buffer
// Create depth stencil texture
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(descDepth));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format =DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = dev->CreateTexture2D( &descDepth, NULL, &g_pDepthStencil);
if(FAILED(hr))
    exit(hr);

// Create the depth stencil view
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
ZeroMemory(&descDSV, sizeof(descDSV));

descDSV.Format = descDepth.Format;
descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;;  
//descDSV.Texture2DMS.UnusedField_NothingToDefine = 0;  

hr = dev->CreateDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencil, &descDSV, &g_pDepthStencilView);
if(FAILED(hr))
    exit(hr);
devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, g_pDepthStencilView);
D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
viewport.Width = width;
viewport.Height = height;

devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
```

This is my code for rendering:

```
void Direct3DRenderer::Render()
{

    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f));
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView,  D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH|D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0 );
    camera.location = simulation->GetWorld()->GetCameraCoordinates();
    camera.direction = simulation->GetWorld()->GetCameraLookAt();
    //camera.up = simulation->GetWorld()->GetCameraOrientation();
    Vec3d lookAt = camera.location + camera.direction;
    XMVECTOR eye = XMVectorSet((float)camera.location[0], (float)camera.location[1], (float)camera.location[2], 0.f);
    XMVECTOR look = XMVectorSet(lookAt[0], lookAt[1], lookAt[2], 0);
    XMVECTOR up = XMVectorSet(camera.up[0], camera.up[1], camera.up[2], 0);
    g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH(eye, look, up);

    ConstantBuffer oncePerFrame;
    oncePerFrame.matrix = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(oncePerFrameBuffer, 0, NULL, &oncePerFrame, 0, 0);

    UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT offset = 0;

    const std::vector<Graphical*> graphicalList = simulation->GetWorld()->GetGraphicalList();

    for(int ind = 0; ind < graphicalList.size(); ++ind)
    {
        switch(graphicalList[ind]->GetModelType())
        {
            case 1:  //Sphere
                {
                    ConstantBuffer oncePerModel2;
                    oncePerModel2.matrix = XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixScalingFromVector(graphicalList[ind]->GetScaleX()) * XMMatrixTranslationFromVector(graphicalList[ind]->GetTranslationX()));
                    devcon->UpdateSubresource(oncePerModelBuffer, 0, NULL, &oncePerModel2, 0, 0);
                    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &(sphereModel.vertexBuffer), &stride, &offset);
                    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(sphereModel.indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
                    devcon->DrawIndexed(sphereModel.indexCount, 0, 0);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    ConstantBuffer oncePerModel;
    oncePerModel.matrix = XMMatrixTranspose(g_World);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(oncePerModelBuffer, 0, NULL, &oncePerModel, 0, 0);

    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &terrainModel.vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(terrainModel.indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    devcon->DrawIndexed(terrainModel.indexCount, 0, 0);

    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

I have tried searching extensively, and have followed every tutorial I could find.  Nothing fixes it.

In the case of the spheres, depth appears to be correct if viewing from one side, but not the other.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This is just a guess but have you tried clearing the depth buffer with 0.0 instead of 1.0?

Comment: Just tried.  It just makes nothing show.  Which makes sense, because I believe it's setting every pixel to already be set to depth 0, so nothing could possibly be closer than it, so everything will be discarded.

Comment: did you try `*your3ddevice*->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);` ?

Comment: Can you get the depth buffer as a texture and look at it? It could indicate what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

From OP comment:

> The problem ended up being much simpler. I did not set the minimum and
>   max depth for the viewport object. It worked once I did so.

I had the same problem, it works now:

```
D3D11_VIEWPORT screenViewport;
/* ... */
screenViewport.MinDepth = 0;
screenViewport.MaxDepth = 1;
/* ... */
context->RSSetViewports(1, &screenViewport);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three key steps to Z-Buffering.

1. Setting the Appropriate Presentation Parameters
2. Turning On Z-Buffering
3. Clearing the Z-Buffer

1)  Setting the Appropriate Presentation Parameters

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
//...
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
```

EnableAutoDepthStencil

In truth, z-buffering can be complex.  Setting this value to TRUE tells Direct3D to automatically create the z-buffer and set it up in a way used most often.  There are, of course, uses for the complex method, but we'll stick to simple for now.  We'll cover ways the complex method can be useful later in the tutorial.

AutoDepthStencilFormat

This is the format for each pixel in the z-buffer.  We don't use the regular pixel format defined in the Presentation Parameters.  Instead, we use a special format for z-buffers.  This format is D3DFMT_D16.  This means that each pixel is 16-bit.  There are other formats, but we will not need them for the extent of this tutorial.

2)  Turning On Z-Buffering

```
// d3ddev is your Direct3D device - a variable of type LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9
d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);
```

3)  Clearing the Z-Buffer

```
d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
```

By the way this works in DirectX 9.0c. Im not sure if it is compatible with DirectX 11.

Comment: The problem ended up being much simpler.  I did not set the minimum and max depth for the viewport object.  It worked once I did so.

Comment: I think this is not Direct3D 11 either is it? Looks like earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem in DirectX10, seems it was initialisation code, I am not sure about the CreateDevice and SwapChain against UNKNOWN driver type, as I have not used that before.

There are a few differences I can see, the Stencil buffer does not specify the operations to perform depth stencil tests against. (Unless this has been specified in the HLSL which is not visible here)

eg:

```
// Stencil test parameters
dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
dsDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
```

In any event, here is a working DirectX10 example, I am pretty sure you can adapt it quickly for DirectX11.

```
logger->debug("initD3D: Calling D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain.\n");

SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
GetSystemTime(&sysTime);
srand((unsigned int)sysTime.wMilliseconds);
logger->debug("in initD3D.\n");
shutdownXX = false;

count = 1;
quality = 0;

//Create the back buffer desc.
ZeroMemory(&swapDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

swapDesc.BufferCount = 1;
swapDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
swapDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;

swapDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
swapDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
swapDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
swapDesc.SampleDesc.Count = count;
swapDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = quality;
swapDesc.Windowed = FALSE;


swapDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
swapDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
swapDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

//Create the device.
HRESULT hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        NULL, 
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        D3D10_SDK_VERSION, 
        &swapDesc, 
        &swapChain, 
        &device);
if (!chk(hr, TEXT("Could not create D3D Device D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain failed.")))
    return false;

ID3D10Texture2D *buffer;

logger->debug("initD3D: Calling swapChain->GetBuffer.\n");
hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (LPVOID*) &buffer);
if (!chk(hr, TEXT("Could not create D3D Device: swapChain->GetBuffer failed.")))
    return false;

D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC BBDesc;
ZeroMemory(&BBDesc, sizeof(D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
buffer->GetDesc( &BBDesc );

D3D10_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC RTVDesc;
ZeroMemory(&RTVDesc, sizeof(D3D10_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC));
RTVDesc.Format = BBDesc.Format;
//RTVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
RTVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D10_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
RTVDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

logger->debug("initD3D: Calling device->CreateRenderTargetView.\n");
hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(buffer, &RTVDesc, &renderTView);
buffer->Release();

if (!chk(hr, TEXT("Could not create D3D Device: device->CreateRenderTargetView failed.")))
    return false;


ZeroMemory(&descDepth, sizeof(D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT;
//descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = count;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = quality;
descDepth.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &stencil);
if (!chk(hr, TEXT("device->device->CreateTexture2D Failed\n")))
    return false;

// Depth test parameters
dsDesc.DepthEnable = true;
dsDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D10_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
dsDesc.DepthFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_LESS;

// Stencil test parameters
dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
dsDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

// Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

// Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D10_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D10_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;


hr = device->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDesc, &pDSState);
if (!chk(hr, TEXT("device->device->CreateDepthStencilState Failed\n")))
    return false;
device->OMSetDepthStencilState(pDSState, 1);

ZeroMemory(&descDSV, sizeof(D3D10_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
descDSV.Format = descDepth.Format;
//descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D10_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D10_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

hr = device->CreateDepthStencilView(stencil, &descDSV, &depthStencil);
if (!chk(hr, TEXT("device->device->CreateDepthStencilView Failed\n")))
    return false;

device->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTView, depthStencil);

resizeD3D10Window(width, height);

return true;
```